# Calculating ETH mining profitability

Tags: mining

I'm new to the mining business and am just trying to calculate some profitability as an exercise.

I'm looking at this Bitmain S17 Pro mining rig: https://shop.bitmain.com/promote/antminer_s17pro/specification

In it's specifications, it says it 50 TH/s hash rate with a power consumption of 2250W.

[image]

Plugging this into a ETH mining profitability calculator, I get:

[image]

Seems I can make $100M+ per month??

Obviously I'm missing something here. Can anyone help me understand why my calculations are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The current hashrate for the entire Ethereum mainnet is [~570 TH/s](https://etherscan.io/chart/hashrate).

The claimed 53 TH/s would therefore equate to ~10% of the entire network... I'm suspecting that their TH/s rate isn't measured using Ethereum's Ethash algorithm.